# Pass another view as parameter in data binding

Tags: java, android, android-databinding

I am trying to pass a another view of my xml as a parameter of a method in Google data binding... like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/faq_subject_about_ego"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/border_faq_btn"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:onClick='@{(faq_title_about) -> viewModel.subjectRequest(faq_title_about.getText())}'>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_faq"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:clickable="false" />

    <ebanx.com.ego.utils.custom_extension.CustomButtonBold
        android:id="@+id/faq_title_about"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Button_FAQ"
        android:text="@string/btn_about_ego"
        android:clickable="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I need the text that is in my CustomButtonBold... But this is not working.

**How can I pass the text of the button as a parameter?**

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The member generated for the id-able has a CamelCase name format. Also the view provided to the `OnClickListener` is the view being clicked. So just name the parameter arbitrarily and use the correct "global" member.

```
android:onClick='@{(v) -> viewModel.subjectRequest(faqTitleAbout.getText())}'
```

Comment: Why doesn't ot work for me with Android Studio 4.1.2 ? It doesn't compile

Comment: @Sergiob I'd suggest to create a new question with your specific problem, including the error from the binding generator. Feel free to leave a link here as well...

Answer (score 7):

If you are coding in Kotlin you could be tempted to write the following:

```
android:onClick='@{(v) -> viewModel.subjectRequest(faqTitleAbout.text)}'
```

It won't work, because the binding class is generated by the framework in Java. Another problem is that with EditText views you need to add also a call to

> toString()

If you want to call a function that takes a string as parameter. So the code would be:

```
android:onClick='@{(v) -> viewModel.subjectRequest(faqTitleAbout.getText().toString())}'
```

That's how it works with Kotlin and Android Studio 4.1.2, otherwise you get a build error (...a weird one...). I don't know if that will change in the future or it has a different behavior with other versions.